# Regex in Sublime Text tmLanguage file doesn't use multiline

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create a custom syntax language file to highlight and help with creating new documents in Sublime Text 2. I have come pretty far, but I'm stuck at a specific problem regarding Regex searches in the tmLanguage file. I simply want to be able to match a regex over multiple lines within a YAML document that I then convert to PList to use in Sublime Text as a package. It won't work.

[This](https://regex101.com/r/iH3gL0/1) is my regex:

```
/(foo[^.#]*bar)/
```

And this is how it looks inside the tmLanguage YAML document:

```
patterns:
- include: '#test'

repository:
  test:
    comment: Tester pattern
    name: constant.numeric.xdoc
    match: (foo[^.#]*bar)
```

If I build this YAML to a tmLanguage file and use it as a package in Sublime Text, I create a document that uses this custom syntax, try it out and the following happens:

This WILL match:

```
foo 12345 bar
```

This WILL NOT match:

```
foo
12345
bar
```

In [a Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/iH3gL0/1), they should and will both match, but in my tmLanguage file it does not work.

I also already tried to add modifiers to my regex in the tmLanguage file, but the following either don't work or break the document entirely:

```
match: (/foo[^.#]*bar/gm)
match: /(/foo[^.#]*bar/)/gm
match: /foo[^.#]*bar/gm
match: foo[^.#]*bar
```

> Note: My Regex rule works in the tester, this problem occurs in the tmLanguage file in Sublime Text 2 only.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The reason I use a match instead of begin/end clauses is because I want to use capture groups to give them different names. If someone has a solution with begin and end clauses where you can still name 'foo', '12345' and 'bar' differently, that's fine by me too.

Comment: I apologize, I answered before testing :) I'm going to delete and answer later.

Comment: Try something like `name: my.new.variable // contentName: string.other // begin: 'foo' // end: 'bar' // patterns: // - include: $self // - name: support.keyword //   match: [^.#]` (please reformat as comments do not allow newlines).

Comment: Did you have time to check? I believe you need to check [this page for more help](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#begin-end-rules).

Comment: I know about begin and end clauses, but i need to number the different sections between the '#' and '.' characters. That's why I use my Regex, because I can use capture groups to name them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that this is impossible to do. This is directly from the [TextMate Manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars), which is the text editor Sublime Text is based on.

> ## 12.2 Language Rules
>
> <...>
>
> Note that the regular expressions **are matched against only a single
> line of the document at a time**. That means it is **not possible to use a
> pattern that matches multiple lines**. The reason for this is technical:
> being able to restart the parser at an arbitrary line and having to
> re-parse only the minimal number of lines affected by an edit. In most
> situations it is possible to use the begin/end model to overcome this
> limitation.

My situation is one of the few in which a begin/end model cannot overcome the limitation. Unfortunate.

Comment: this is disappointing. recently ran into the same issue (in vscode). Did you find any alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Long time since asked, but are you sure you can't use begin/end? I had similar problems with begin/end until I got a better grasp of the syntax/logic. Here's a rough example from a json tmLanguage file I'm doing (don't know the proper YAML syntax).

```
"repository": {

"foobar": {
    "begin": "foo(?=[^.#]*)", // not sure about what's needed for your circumstance. the lookahead probably only covers the foo line
    "end": "bar",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "0": {
            "name": "foo"
        }
    },
    "endCaptures": {
        "0": {
            "name": "bar"
        }
    },
    "patterns": [
        {"include": "#test-after-foobarmet"}
    ]
},
"test-after-foobarmet": {
    "comment": "this can apply to many lines before next bar so you may need more testing",
    "comment2": "you could continue to have captures here that go to another deeper level...",
    "name": "constant.numeric.xdoc",
    "match": "anyOtherRegexNeeded?"
}

}
```

I didn't follow your

> "i need to number the different sections between the '#' and '.'
>   characters."

, but you should be able to have a test in `test-after-foobarmet` with more captures if needed for naming different groups between foo bar.

There's are good [explanation of TextMate Grammar here](https://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/textmatebundle.html). May still suffer from some errors but explains it in a way that was helpful for me when I didn't know anything about the topic.

Comment: Oh boy, this was years ago... I do remember the issue though. Let's say you want to find the multi-line keyword "begin-tag-abc.content.end-tag". I would be able to do this using begin and end clauses in the language file, but I would be unable to extract the "abc" piece of data, if it could contain something besides "abc".

Comment: In the example you made, imagine that the "foo" begin capture could also be "fao" or "fbo" or "fco", how do I retrieve that data?